# Display TextView when EditText is not empty

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm working with an Android application and have encountered the following problem.

**Problem:** I want a TextView to display some text when two edittext fields are not empty (when there are text written in the edittext fields).

**What I have done:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle   
savedInstanceState) {
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_to_speech, container, false);  
...

if(edittextbox1.getText().toString().length() !=0 && edittextbox2.getText().toString().length() !=0) {
    textview.setText("some text")
} 
return rootView;
}
```

This does not work. The text view never pops up. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this add TextWatcher to both edit text. You can get the text changed for both edit text and then you get the length and show your textView if the condition is true.

```
TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int st, int b, int c)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int st, int c, int a)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
            if(edittextbox1.getText().toString().length() != 0 && edittextbox2.getText().toString().length() != 0) {
                 textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 textview.setText("some text");
             }
        }
    };

  edittextbox1.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
  edittextbox2.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use something like this to listen to your `EditText` fields.

```
edittextbox1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

edittextbox1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int st, int b, int c) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int st, int c, int a) 
    {
       if(edittextbox1.getText().toString().length() !=0) {
       textview.setText("some text")
  } 
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
    {
        if(edittextbox1.getText().toString().length() !=0) {
        textview.setText("some text")
  } 
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you know if there is a easy way to look at both 'edittextbox1' og 'edittextbox2'?

Answer (score 0):

pls try set visibility of your textview

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle   
savedInstanceState) {
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_to_speech, container, false);  
...

if(edittextbox1.getText().toString().length() !=0 && edittextbox2.getText().toString().length() !=0) {
    textview.setText("some text");
     textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} 
return rootView;
}
```

Comment: this either won't work because he needs to listen to text changes

Answer (score -1):

Do it like this. It will work!

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle   
savedInstanceState) {
   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_to_speech, container, false); 
   EditText edittextbox1=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.your_edittext_id1); 
   EditText edittextbox2=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.your_edittext_id2);
   TextView textView=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.your_textview_id1);

   if ((edittextbox1.getText().toString().length() != 0) && (edittextbox2.getText().toString().length() != 0)) {
        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        textview.setText("some text");
   } else {
        textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }
   return rootView;
}
```